# Ionic fcm plugin, onNotification function not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, observable, ionic-native

I am trying to implement FCM to send notifications to app users using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Though, I am unable to receive any notifications on my phone while debugging the app.

I am trying to explicitly send the request using postman on, https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. This is the following request:

```
{
    "registration_ids": [
        "my_random_device_ids"
    ],
    "notification": {
        "title": "New request",
        "body": "Your action required to accept.",
        "content_available": false,
        "priority": "high",
        "sound": "default",
        "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
    },
    "data": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

This is my code to receive the notification in the application:

```
    this.fcm.getToken().then(
        (token) => {
            console.log(token);
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log("FCM", err);
        }
    );
    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
    this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(async token => {
        var deviceType = this.platform.is('android') ? 'Android' : 'iOS'
        var deviceDetails = { deviceID: this.deviceUUID, deviceToken: token, deviceType: deviceType };
        await this.authService.insertUpdateDeviceToken(deviceDetails);
    });
```

I receive the notification in the background, regardless of declaring `this.fcm.onNotification()`.
Also, when I declare it, it doesn't log anything, which means it is not working. Is there a way to tackle this?

Comment: I think there's an issue in the android.manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It is similar to this but, uses the main package instead of `@ionic-native/fcm` wrapper library.

The working code is as follows, to implement fcm, in an ionic project built over angular.

> In cmd[your project directory]

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@7.3.1
```

Now, please make sure in your projects, within plugins folder, a folder named `cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated` is present and within it, there is a sub folder `ionic` and within this sub folder there is another sub folder `ngx`.

Now, you can use it in your code, I use it in app.component.ts

```
import { FCM } from 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx';
// Initialise in constructor
.
.
.
.
this.fcm.getToken().then(function(token) {
    console.log(token);
}).catch(err) {
    console.log(err, 'Unable to get token');
});

this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
});

this.fcm.onTokenRefresh(). subscribe (async token => {
    console.log(token);
});
```

Now, it works properly. You can try sending a notification to on the token you receive.

Comment: i tried this but not worked for me no error is given just app stucked to loading